# How to append and remove ids on the basis of checkbox checked unchecked in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below lines of code in javascript

```js
$(document).on("change", ".commoncheckbox", function() {
    var studentIds = $("#allStudentIds").val().trim();
    $("#tagsOfStudents").show();
    $("#empty_row").remove();
    var id = $(this).val();
    var generatedString;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      if (studentIds == "") {
        generatedString = id;
      } else {
        generatedString = studentIds + "," + id;
      }
      var uniqueList = generatedString.split(',').filter(function(item, i, allItems) {
        return i == allItems.indexOf(item);
      }).join(',');
      $("#allStudentIds").val(uniqueList);
      var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
      var name = $td.eq(2).text();
      var gender = $td.eq(4).text();
      var className = $td.eq(3).text();
      var deleteButton = '<button title="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(\'' + id + '\')" class="btn btn-danger  table_btn btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
      var html = '<tr id=row_' + id + '>' + '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + className + '</td>' + '<td>' + gender + '</td>' + '<td>' + deleteButton + '</td>' + '</tr>';
      if ($('#row_' + id).length > 0) {} else {
        $("#selected_students").append(html);
      }
    } else {
      if ($('#row_' + id).length > 0) {
        $("#row_" + id).remove();
      }
    }
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
    <th></th>
    ...
  </thead>

  <tbody id="studentListBody">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" value="578" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="allStudentIds">
```

I have added checkboxes with class commoncheckbox inside table body "*studentListBody*". On the basis of checking and unchecking the checkboxes, the table's data gets successfully appended and deleted respectively inside another table "selected_student". Additionally on the basis of checking and unchecking the checkboxes, I am trying to append the ids of the students (the values of the checked checkboxes) to the hidden input in the line `$("#allStudentIds").val(uniqueList);` .

Here is how it is storing in hidden input tag whenever checkbox is checked:

```
input type="hidden" value="5ae957dbbb2c561a10003dc7,5ae9584bbb2c561a10003dca,5ae958a4bb2c561a10003dcc" id="allStudentIds">
```

Now I am trying to tweak the above code for removing the id from hidden input whenever the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple way is to use `replace` maybe there is a better solution than this but it's not in my head right now

```js
$(document).on("change", ".commoncheckbox", function() {
    var studentIds = $("#allStudentIds").val().trim();
    $("#tagsOfStudents").show();
    $("#empty_row").remove();
    var id = $(this).val();
    var generatedString;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      if (studentIds == "") {
        generatedString = id;
      } else {
        generatedString = studentIds + "," + id;
      }
      var uniqueList = generatedString.split(',').filter(function(item, i, allItems) {
        return i == allItems.indexOf(item);
      }).join(',');
      $("#allStudentIds").val(uniqueList);
      var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
      var name = $td.eq(2).text();
      var gender = $td.eq(4).text();
      var className = $td.eq(3).text();
      var deleteButton = '<button title="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(\'' + id + '\')" class="btn btn-danger  table_btn btn-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
      var html = '<tr id=row_' + id + '>' + '<td>' + name + '</td>' + '<td>' + className + '</td>' + '<td>' + gender + '</td>' + '<td>' + deleteButton + '</td>' + '</tr>';
      if ($('#row_' + id).length > 0) {} else {
        $("#selected_students").append(html);
      }
    } else {
      var removeId = studentIds.replace( ','+id+',' , '').replace( ','+id , '').replace( id+',' , '').replace(id , '');
      $("#allStudentIds").val(removeId);
      if ($('#row_' + id).length > 0) {
        $("#row_" + id).remove();
      }
    }
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
    <th></th>
    ...
  </thead>

  <tbody id="studentListBody">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" value="578" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" value="" id="allStudentIds">
```